# where else can "ro.product.cpu.abilist" be changed?

Tags: java, android, shell

Where else can the abilist value be set except "build.prop"?

```
 adb shell cat /system/build.prop | grep -i abi
# ro.product.cpu.abi and ro.product.cpu.abi2 are obsolete,
# use ro.product.cpu.abilist instead.
ro.product.cpu.abi=x86
ro.product.cpu.abilist64=
# Capabilities
# Screencast / screenshot capability
# Remote controller capability
# Network control capability
# Disk IO throttling capability
```

```
 adb shell getprop | grep -i abi
[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [x86]
[ro.product.cpu.abi2]: [armeabi-v7a]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist]: [x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist32]: [x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist64]: []
```

clearly the android abilist prop is not consistent with that in build.prop?
where else did it get set?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

it is set in /etc/init.genymotion.sh  after some time studying it.